# How to distinguish between the amount of the real input amount and the decoys

Tags: ringct, privacy, amounts

Since every transaction has multiple decoys from previous transactions that are connected to it (while only one is real), how does the user link the amount that is linked to the "real" transaction?

EDIT: What is the math behind discarding the unnecessary "decoy" values, when checking the Pedersen commitment (of our output and *the real* inputs).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Since every transaction has multiple decoys from previous transactions that are connected to it (while only one is real), how does the user link the amount that is linked to the "real" transaction?

Firstly, all the decoy outputs are "real", they are real outputs created by previous transactions.

Second, the whole point of the decoys is to *not* be able to determine which is the real output being spent. The signer is proving they own one in each set/ring, but not which.

Third, the *amounts* for the generated outputs are encrypted in the transaction `ecdhInfo` field. Thus to obtain the decoy encrypted amounts, you grab them from the `ecdhInfo` of the transactions that created those outputs.

> EDIT: What is the math behind discarding the unnecessary "decoy" values, when checking the Pedersen commitment (of our output and the real inputs).

There is no "discarding the unnecessary "decoy" values". I suggest reading 5.4 in [Zero to Monero](https://web.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-2-0-0.pdf) which goes into greater detail, but to summarize: The input commitments included in the tx, are actually *pseudo* output commitments. These pseudo output commitments use the same original *amounts* but use different *binding* factors. As the sender knows the *difference* between the commitments, they can use this as the commitment to zero and sign.

Thus

```
     C = xG + aH
    C' = x'G + aH
C - C' = (x - x')G
     z = x - x'
```

Where `x'` is a new binding factor, `C'` is a pseudo output commitment and `z` being the private key of our commitment to zero.

With regards to your comment of "checking the Pedersen commitment", I presume you are referring to checking the sum of inputs and outputs is zero. For this, one is checking the sum of the pseudo output commitments (the inputs) minus the sum of the tx output commitments.

[image]

Of course one also needs to ensure none of the values are negative, and this is the purpose of the range proof (see Zero to Monero 5.5).

Comment: Thanks, buy my question was about the mechanism/math that let us to discard the decoys' encrypted values from the calculation.

Comment: There is no "discard the decoys' encrypted values". I have added an update based on your edit and hope that is what you are trying to understand.

Comment: Thanks again!  I don't understand why the signer can know $x-x'$, since x is unknown and to get $(x-x')$ from $(x-x')G$ is hard as DLP

Comment: Each mask (binding factor) used to be (pre v2BP) stored in `ecdhInfo`. Now however, the masks are deterministically derived.

Comment: maybe I still don't understand. the pseudo commitment are for Tx that the signer had received? and what do u mean deterministically derived? that we can compute x from xG?

Comment: Deterministically derived: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm. For the pseudo output commitment `x`s, they are created / worked-out in a deterministic way. Obviously one cannot calculate `x` from `xG`, but for the purposes of the pseudo output commitments, all that's required is that anyone can create the `x`s when constructing the pseudo out commitments. As I said, these `x`s *used* to be attached in `ecdhInfo`, now they are deterministically derived instead, which saves tx space.